# Why doesn't work rack-cors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rack

config/application.rb

```
require_relative 'boot'
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MyApp
 class Application < Rails::Application
  config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :patch, :delete]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack-cors'

another gems…
```

bundle exec rake middleware

```
use Rack::Cors

another middleware…
```

This is an error shown console log

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.`

What should i do??

Comment: do you use Rails 5 or Rails 4?

Comment: @MuhamadAkbarBinWidayat I use Rails 5!

Comment: Read the error message again. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com`. It does not matter how many cors headers you send on localhost if you are loading data from `https://example.com`. ;)

Comment: You can try asking [IANA](https://www.iana.org/) really nicely if they will add CORS headers on example.com...

Comment: @max thank you for the comment! But I don’t understand what i should do… I’m sorry. If you’d like,  could you tell me what i should do specific thing?

Comment: Search your project code for `example.com`. Somewhere in there you are making an ajax call to `example.com`. I'm guessing you copy-pasted some code without actually reading or understanding it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your code into like this. I have tried in my rails 5 only add below lines will work. Then try to restart the server.

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Rails 5

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I hope it works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But sorry, the error message didn't change…

Comment: This does not answer the question. The error message clearly states that an Ajax request is being made to `http://example.com` (The IANA example domain) and not localhost. The CORS headers on the rails server are in fact totally irrelevant.